# pythonic way of selecing a random value that satisfies a certain predicate

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of elements and I want to randomly select an element from the list that satisfies a predicate. What is the pythonic way of doing this?

I currently  do a comprehension followed by a `random.choice()` but that is unnecessarily inefficient :

```
intlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
evenlist = [ i for i in intlist if i % 2 == 0 ] 
randomeven = random.choice(evenlist)
```

Thanks!

Comment: even the _random_ picker has to know what to choose from. that additional line of code does hurt you?

Comment: I'd say it depends on how many items are excluded by your predicate. If it is less then 50%, then first choosing an item randomly and testing the predicate afterwards might be more efficient. On the other side, if only a few items meet your predicate, filtering them beforehand might be better.

Comment: @Felix_Kling even if you exclude less than 50% of the items from the list there is no way of knowing how long it would take to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written it above is actually good idiomatic python.  If we analyze the algorithm we'll find it's essentially doing this:

1. Making a list of elements that satisfy the predicate.  (Grows linearly with n)
2. Choosing a random element from that list. (Constant time)

The only other way to go about it would be to choose an element at random, decide if it satisfies the predicate, and choose again if it does not.  This algorithm is a little more complex.  In the case where 90% of the list satisfies the predicate, this will run much faster than your solution.  In the case where only 10% of the list satisfies the predicate, it will actually run much slower, because there's a good chance it will randomly select a given element and check if the predicate is satisfied on that element more than once.  Now you could consider memoizing your predicate, but you're still going to select a lot of random data.  It comes down to this:  Unless your solution is particularly unsuited for your data, stick with it, because it's great.  Personally, I'd rewrite it like this:

```
intlist = range(1,10)
randomeven = random.choice([i for i in intlist if i % 2 == 0])
```

This is a little more concise, but it's going to run exactly the same as your existing code.

Comment: +1 sometimes you want to rejection sample. Sometimes you *have* to rejection sample, like when you cannot enumerate all possible choices. But, you couldn't be using `random.choice` in that case...

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a function sort of `random.selectspecific(list, predicate)` in the documentation, so I would try something like the following:

```
import random
def selectspecific(l, predicate):
    result = random.choice(l)
    while (not predicate(result)):
        result = random.choice(l)
    return result
```

Comment: nice. it can be modified to be in accordance with DRY principle using while True / break loop

Comment: there no way of knowing how expensive this solution is going to be, it could take "forever" to take a valid element from the list. Filtering first seems like the best solution.

Comment: If no element in the list returns True from the `predicate()` then this will infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

intlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
randomeven = random.choice(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, intlist))
```

Comment: I posted the same answer with itertools.ifilter. However it doesnt work because random.choice needs to know the actual lenght of the data. Of course!

Comment: This is just a slightly-less-readable version of the code in his question. A filter with a lambda is effectively the same as a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

How pythonic is this?

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
from random import choice
print choice([ i for i in ifilterfalse(lambda x: x%2, range(10)) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to encapsulate more you could create a method to handle the selection, that would accept a predicate method. You can then use this predicate method with `filter()`.

```
import random
def selectSpecific(intlist, predicate):
  filteredList = filter(predicate, intlist)
  result = random.choice(filteredList)
  return result
```

You can pass a predicate to `selectSpecific()` as a `lambda` or any other method. Example:

```
intlist = range(1,10)
selectSpecific(intlist, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)

def makeEven(n):
  if n % 2 == 0:
    return n

selectSpecific(intlist, makeEven)
```